Ошибка при запуске пакет (.deb) в Linux. (dependency is not satisfiable: libffi7)
Я скачал пакет, который хотел установить, но при установке система выдала ошибку: dependency is not satisfiable: libffi7. Я полагаю, что это связано с тем, что у меня установлена новая версия Linux, в которой больше не поддерживается libffi7.
Как мне решить эту проблему? Что нужно сделать, чтобы установить пакет, который требует libffi7, или как можно использовать более новую версию libffi, если это возможно?

Выбросить этот пакет и найти другой способ установки

@andreymal Вы имеете ввиду другой способ установки пакета .deb?

Это уже зависит от того что найдёте. Найдёте другой пакет .deb с актуальным libffi — прекрасно, не найдёте — ну придётся компилировать из исходиков например (если исходники в принципе есть)
